# Preventing an App from changing to Portrait Orientation when the Device is unlocked

Tags: android, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing a game that runs in a wrapped webview for Android devices. Everything is working as expected--in this case, I have locked my view to landscape orientation, and prevented the device from restarting the activity if the phone is rotated.

However, if I put my device to sleep and then unlock it, I see my application in portrait mode for a moment, until my device re-orients to landscape.  This behavior makes sense, since a phone is naturally used in portrait orientation, but I don't want my activity to switch from landscape.

If I start any other game, by which I mean those presumable written in native code, that is locked into landscape mode, and then lock and unlock my phone, the game doesn't do the same quickly-switch-from-portrait-to-landscape dance.

What am I missing?

In MainActivity I have

this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE)

in several places, including onConfigurationChanged, onWindowFocusChanged, onPause, and onResume.

Here is how my activity is defined in my AndroidManifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Thanks for any help/advise!

-J.L.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to remove sensor from the screenOrientation tag. Try this:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: That didn't fix the issue, unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

the app still shows as the incorrect orientation for a split second when the phone is unlocked.

Did you move setContentView(R.layout.main) to the onResume, AFTER where you put your orientation code? I would try setting the orientation, then the setContentView()

Comment: Well, adding setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) to onResume did create the behavior I want, however, my application is now a blank screen. Is this possibly creating a second activity over my initial one? I can hear my game's music playing, so I know my game code is running...